# Error adding timestamp to log file name (log4j2)

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to configure `log4j2` to add a timestamp to the log file as follows:

```
<File name="LogFile" 
      fileName="log/filename.log"
      filePattern="log/filename-%d{yyyy-mm-dd}.log">
</File>
```

but the following error is reported:

```
ERROR File contains an invalid element or attribute "filePattern"
```

If I remove the `filePattern` attribute a log file called `filename.log` is successfully created.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileAppender only accepts a file name, not a pattern. You can use a lookup to get the date if that is what you want.